# How to get value of file upload by field name, not id?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using a plugin with Wordpress for contact forms, and have a file upload. I can't assign an "ID" or class to the field, it only has a name. How can I select this field to get the value and display it in a text field? I was using this code, which worked perfectly when the upload field had an ID.. So I need to figure out how to modify it to work with just a field name.. The name is "CustomFormsFileUpload_945"

```
$(function() {
    $("#ufo-field-id-945").change(function() {
        $("#ufo-field-id-948").val($(this).val())

        var string = $("#ufo-field-id-948").val();
        var new_string = string.replace('C:\\fakepath\\', '');
        $("#ufo-field-id-948").val(new_string);

    });
});​
```

Comment: Both 945 and 948, or just 945 this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector:

```
$('[name="CustomFormsFileUpload_945"]')
```

(And if you don't actually have both `945` and `948` there, you should keep it in a variable.)